# Subnet information in IP Header

Tags: header, ip, mask, subnet

this is my first time so please bear with me. Suppose I have two PCs (A and B) directly connected to each other via a LAN cable. PC A's IP address is 192.168.1.1/24. PC B's IP address is 192.168.1.5/30. Now two PCs wont be able to reach each other because of different subnets (or their subnet masks are not proper for direct connectivity between the two). But the question is that subnet mask information is not sent in IP header so how does PCs come to know if packet coming from another 192.168.1.X address is on different subnet. 
     Reading on different websites, I came to know that devices (eg. PC) maintain its own routing table and make decisions based on it. But still it is not that clear. Please let me know. Must be something very basic which I am not getting.

Thanks,

Mandeep

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.howtogeek.com/169540/what-exactly-is-a-mac-address-used-for/

Answer (score 0):

Both devices will use broadcast messages to find other hosts on the same ethernet network. Considering that these 2 hosts have different subnet masks, the broadcast address will differ, and quite possibly, the 2 hosts will ignore one another. This also has to do with the internal routing of the host operating system, and arp address resolution of these 2 hosts - but in short, best to get configure both hosts with the same subnet mask.